# restkit 0.20 - (void) objectLoader didLoadObjects & other old methods

Tags: ios, xcode, restkit

I'm a little confused about restkit 0.20, I know they added AFNetworking and so they rewrote a lot of methods.
Now I am searching for methods which are almost the same like the objektLoaders one, for example I would like to use:

```
1.
- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader *)objectLoader didLoadObjects:(NSArray *)objects {}
2.
- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader *)objectLoader didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{}
3.
- (void)objectLoaderDidFinishLoading:(RKObjectLoader *)objectLoader{}
```

Would somebody be so kind and give me a hint for the right way? Thanks alot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check out their [wiki page](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Upgrading-from-v0.10.x-to-v0.20.0) on migrating to 0.20.0

the example from that page related to the question seems to be:

this

```
[ [RKObjectManager sharedManager] loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"/examples" usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader *loader) {
    loader.onDidLoadObjects = ^(NSArray *objects) {
        NSLog(@"It Worked: %@", objects);
    };
    loader.onDidFailWithError = ^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"It Failed: %@", error);
    };
}];
```

becomes

```
[RKObjectManager.sharedManager getObjectsAtPath:path parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult)
{
    NSLog(@"It Worked: %@", [mappingResult array]);
    // Or if you're only expecting a single object:
    NSLog(@"It Worked: %@", [mappingResult firstObject]);
} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"It Failed: %@", error);
}];
```

Comment: yeah i think that was part of the redesign. AFNetworking uses blocks quite a bit so it makes sense